# NSFetchedResultsController with predicate gets NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete after update

Tags: ios, core-data

There is some serious issue with `NSFetchedResultsController` which has a predicate. the issue occurs after a value is updated for a property of a contact. so that's how its configured:

```
    NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Contacts" inManagedObjectContext:_addressbookMainObjectContext

    NSSortDescriptor *sortNameDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"lastnameFirstLetter" ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortNameDescriptor1 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"firstName" ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortNameDescriptor, sortNameDescriptor1, nil];

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest new];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entityDescription];

    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];


    fetchRequest.predicate =  [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"contactType == 3"];;

    NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController =
    [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                        managedObjectContext:_addressbookMainObjectContext
                                          sectionNameKeyPath:@"sectiononIdentifier"
                                                   cacheName:nil];
    _fetchResultController = fetchedResultsController;
    _fetchResultController.delegate = self;
```

the predicate is set to fetch filtered rows.

and this is how the parent child context is configured:

```
    _addressbookMainObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
    _addressbookMainObjectContext setMergePolicy:NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy];
    _addressbookMainObjectContext setParentContext:_writerContext];


    _writerContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
    [_writerContext setMergePolicy:NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy];
    [_writerContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:_persistentStoreCoordinator];
```

for updating a row another private context is used to do the job:

```
    NSManagedObjectContext *ctx = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
    [ctx setMergePolicy:NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy];
    [ctx setParentContext:[PalDataCache sharedInstance].addressbookMainObjectContext];


    [ctx performBlockAndWait:^{
        NSError *errorAllCons = nil;
        NSArray *allCons = [context executeFetchRequest:allContacts error:&errorAllCons];

        Contacts * contact = [allCons objectAtIndex:0];
        contact.pictureUpdatedForRedownload = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
    }];
```

so after saving the changes in this temporary context. the `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` is getting triggered:

```
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
{
 UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;

switch(type)
{
    case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
        [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
        break;

    case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
    {
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
        break;
    }
    case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
        [self configureCell:(contactCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] atIndexPath:indexPath];
        break;

    case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
        [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
        break;
}
```

}

and this triggers `NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete` that causes the row to get delete from the table but its not deleted from database. after refetching everything is back there. and that's a very bad user experience. the predicate is set according to the user defined filter. the issue doesn't happen if there is no predicate in fetch request. what am I doing wrong? is there a work around for this behaviour?

**edit:**
this issue still occur when i try to update a record on the main context for contacts. so it's then main context and write context combination.

Comment: I didn't dig in enough to see your actual issue, but so you're aware, merge policies do absolutely nothing for child contexts. Their changes, when saved (and thus merged up into the parent), simply trump any conflicting change in the parent context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced the same problem. This is how I fixed:

1. My predicate was using something like ("index == %@")
2. I was filtering an integer value, but I was passing @"1".
3. Changing it to %i and passing integer, worked.